# How to make a 2d grid with c#

Tags: c#, monogame

I want to start making 2d simulations like conway's game of life, pathfinding and sand simulations and so..
I understand the concept and that I have to make a grid...
The thing is that i can't find how to make a grid..
I have tried searching and I don't seem to find a proper tutorial or something helpful...
I am using monogame framework and have some knowledge with c#.
I just want to understand how to make one so i can use it to make simulations if someone can break it down for me or give me an existing tutorial I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grid is implemented in an array of simple values(byte, uint, float...) or objects depending on complexity.

For pathfinding, it is not uncommon to use a parallel grid for indication of visited  or changed nodes.

Game of life example:

```
// class level variables 
const int WIDTH = 32;
const int HEIGHT = 32;
byte[,] Grid = new byte[WIDTH,HEIGHT]; // byte is 1/4 smaller than bool
byte[,] NextGrid = new byte[WIDTH,HEIGHT];
// 1 is alive 0 is dead

//in Initialize()

// build a period 2 Blinker
Grid[5,4] = 1;
Grid[5,5] = 1;
Grid[5,6] = 1;


//in Update()
// follow row major form and  count the 8 possible live neighbors
for (int y=0;y<HEIGHT;y++)
   for (int x=0;x<WIDTH;x++)
   {
      byte nLiveCount = 0;
      if(x > 0) // left 3
      {
         nLiveCount += Grid[x-1,y];
         if(y > 0)
            nLiveCount += Grid[x-1,y-1];
         if(y < HEIGHT - 1)
            nLiveCount += Grid[x-1,y+1];
      }
      if(x < WiDTH - 1) // right 3
      {
         nLiveCount += Grid[x+1,y];
         if(y > 0)
            nLiveCount += Grid[x+1,y-1];
         if(y < HEIGHT - 1)
            nLiveCount += Grid[x+1,y+1];
      }
      if(y < HEIGHT - 1) // above
         nLiveCount += Grid[x,y+1];
      if(y > 0) // below
         nLiveCount += Grid[x,y-1];

      if(Grid[x,y]== 1) // test live
      {
         if((nLiveCount == 2 || nLiveCount ==3))
            NextGrid[x,y] = 1;
      }   
      else
         if(nLiveCount == 3) // birth
            NextGrid[x,y] = 1;
   }
Grid = NextGrid;
NextGrid = new byte[WIDTH,HEIGHT]; // Ready nextGrid for next step

// in Draw()

// this assumes 2 loaded 8x8 textures called black and white
for (int y=0;y<HEIGHT;y++)
   for (int x=0;x<WIDTH;x++)
      spriteBatch.Draw((Grid[x,y]==1)?black:white, new Vector2(8 * x, 8 * y), Color.White);

// could be simplified to a single white texture 8x8 with:
//spriteBatch.Draw(white, new Vector2(8 * x, 8 * y), (Grid[x,y]==1) ? Color.Black : Color.White);
```

Answer (score -1):

For this type of "game" I would rather use .NET MAUI and its Grid. The grid in Monogame can be draw either as a whole image of grid or as an array of lines, for which a 1x1px (but better is the middle pixel of 3x3px) source white image is sufficient (the color can be changed during rendering). This can then be stretched to any width or height to render the entire grid to the screen. You then need to have a 2D array (bool[,]) with a state map in the background for faster processing and redraw the result on the screen.
I have a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxTqV9i8bnb_BN9k_-W_CjXfumNzqiPEe) tutorial and [GitHub](https://github.com/PetrVobornik/ToDe) source code for a tower defense game in Monogame, where I also use grid layout, but it's only in Czech language.

Comment: This is essentially a link only answer as there's not enough information in the answer itself to actually answer the question and, as such, is discouraged in case links break.